# React setState doesn't work when mutating the state directly why not

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-http-99jekw), i am trying to copy the list as another list and modifying the name property, I was wondering why would this not work, i know that shallow copying this works/ also when i use a fn updater it works , thanks

```
    import { useState } from "react";
    
    const initList = { name: "abhi" };
    
    export default function List() {
      const [list, setList] = useState(initList);
    
      function handleClick() {
        const nextList = list;
        nextList.name = "anand";
        // setList((list) => ({ ...list }));
        setList(nextList);
      }
    
      return (
        <>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>change name</button>
          <ul>{list.name}</ul>
        </>
      );
    }
```

Edit: I understand the what and how, wanted to know why this happens in Reactjs. I have got my answer, thank you so much guys for helping me out

Comment: This example is from react docs I just modified for making the point here, i know what works and doesn't but wanted to understand the why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got answers already but to be precise [here's the piece of source code from react repo](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/977bccd24de2b062d2c114e6cf160d2bd9ed9493/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L1197) that I believe is responsible for what you're seeing:

```
// Mark that the fiber performed work, but only if the new state is
// different from the current state.
if (!is(newState, hook.memoizedState)) {
  markWorkInProgressReceivedUpdate();
}
```

You can find the definition of `is` [function here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/977bccd24de2b062d2c114e6cf160d2bd9ed9493/packages/shared/objectIs.js#L14). The important bit is that it compares two passed objects (old state and a new state) by reference. Since you did not make a shallow copy of the new state these are in fact the same and no update is made.

Perhaps an interesting thing is that using functional version of setState does not automatically save you from the same mistake. It also has to return a different reference from the old state.
In other words, this also won't update state:

```
const nextList = list;
nextList.name = "anand";
setList((list) => nextList);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, i know what and how but not why , thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

`const nextList = list` will not create a new object, it will create a variable `nextList` that points to the same object as `list`.

Consequently, when you mutate the object referenced by `nextList`, you're mutating the same  object referenced by `list`.

Read more [here](https://javascript.info/object-copy).

And, as you stated, you already know [state in react shouldn't be mutated](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state#treat-state-as-read-only).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your question, but you would like to keep the object's initial value `{ name: "abhi" }` and on const `nextList` change name to "anand", right? getting like this: `initList = { name: "abhi" }` and `list = { name: "anand" }`? If so, just do this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const initList = { name: "Test 1" };

export default function List() {
  const [list, setList] = useState({ ...initList });

  function handleClick() {
    const nextList = list;
    nextList.name = "Test 2";
    // setList((list) => ({ ...list }));
    setList(nextList);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>change name</button>
      <ul>{list.name}</ul>
      <ul>{initList.name}</ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

This happens because you are inserting the object and its pointer to the state of the `list`, in this case what you need is just the initial values ​​of the object and not the complete one.